# How to add different links to an array of buttons?

Tags: swift3, xcode8

I have a button that is used in view table controller in `xcode 3` and I want all the getbutton on the right side to open different links how can I do this.

[image]

I have no idea how to do this. I have tried to add an array and access them but it didn't work.

Comment: Is this a custom UITableViewCell class? Have you looked into creating a protocol for your cell class and conforming the view controller to that protocol? So when you tap the button, you pass the cell itself to the protocol method to get its index in the implementation and get the  correct index for the array you mentioned.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: I'll send you a picture of my code so you can see what I have

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the tag of the button to the indexPath.row in cellForRow dataSource method.

```
 cell.button.tag = indexPath.row
```

then in the buttons selector function you get the cell at that row.

```
 func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
   guard let tappedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)) as? CustomCellClass, let url = URL(string: tappedCell.modelObject.urlString) else { return }
  //assuming the model object you assign to each cell has a link property, you can now access the link for that cell
  UIApplication.shared.openURL(url) 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of how I would approach this:

```
//This is your custom cell class
----------------------------------
protocol CustomCellProtocol {
    func didTapGet(cell:UITableViewCell)
}

class CustomCell:UITableViewCell {

    var delegate:CustomCellProtocol?

    @IBAction func getTapped(id:Any) {
        delegate?.didTapGet(cell: self)
    }
}
//This is your View controller
-----------------------------------
class YourTableViewController:UIViewController, CustomCellProtocol, UITableViewDataSource {
//Your Code here
    var tableView:UITableView?
    let urlArray = ["www.example1.com", "www.example2.com"]

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellIdentifier") as! CustomCell

        //cell code here
        cell.delegate = self

        return cell
    }

    func didTapGet(cell: UITableViewCell) {
        if let indexPath = tableView?.indexPath(for: cell), let url = URL(string:urlArray[indexPath.row]) {

            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [], completionHandler: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write this code:

```
var Urlarr = ["http://drivecurrent.com/using-swift-and-avfoundation-to-create-a-custom-camera-view-for-an-ios-app/","https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/summary","http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41156065/how-can-i-add-different-links-to-an-array-of-buttons"]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return Urlarr.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = self.TableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! TableViewCell
    cell.TblButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.TblButton.addTarget(self,action:#selector(buttonClicked),
                      for:.touchUpInside)

    return cell
}
func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton)
{
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string: Urlarr[sender.tag]) as! URL)
}
```